# How convincing as a proof of the Inspiration of the Scriptures are the following patterns of 40 (and 41) in the Greek Scriptures?

Tags: greek, word-study, christology, inspiration

There are exactly 40 times in the Greek New Testament Scriptures that God speaks the words 'EGO EIMI' (I AM).

The Deity of Christ | ‘EGO EIMI’ (I AM) | 40 instances

Matthew

1. But straightway Jesus spake unto them, saying, Be of good courage; [I AM  1]; fear not.   Matthew 14:27
2. [I AM  2] The God of Abraham, and The God of Isaac, and The God of Jacob? God is not The God of the dead, but of the living.   Matthew 22:32
3. For many shall come in My Name, saying, [I AM  3] The Christ; and shall deceive many.   Matthew 24:5

Mark

4. For they all saw Him, and were troubled. And immediately He talked with them, and saith unto them, Be of good cheer: [I AM  4]; fear not.   Mark 6:50
5. For many shall come in My Name, saying, [I AM  5] ~; and shall deceive many.   Mark 13:6
6. And Jesus said, [I AM  6]: and ye shall see The Son of man sitting on The Right of Power, and coming in the clouds of Heaven.   Mark 14:62

Luke

7. And He said, Take heed that ye be not deceived: for many shall come in My Name, saying, [I AM  7] ~; and the time draweth near: go ye not therefore after them.   Luke 21:8
8. Then said they all, Art Thou then The Son of God? And He said unto them, Ye say that [I AM  8].   Luke 22:70
9. Behold My Hands and My Feet, that [I AM  9]: handle Me, and see; for a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see Me have.   Luke 24:39

John (23 instances)

10. Jesus saith unto her, [I AM  10] ~ that speak unto thee.   John 4:26
11. But He saith unto them, [I AM  11]; fear not.   John 6:20
12. And Jesus said unto them, [I AM  12] The Bread of Life: he that cometh to Me shall never hunger; and he that believeth on Me shall never thirst.   John 6:35
13. The Jews then murmured at Him, because He said, [I AM  13] The Bread which came down from The Heaven.   John 6:41
14. [I AM  14] The Bread of Life.   John 6:48
15. [I AM  15] The Living Bread which came down from The Heaven: if any man eat of This Bread, he shall live for ever: and The Bread that I will give is My Flesh, which I will give for the life of the world.   John 6:51
16. Then spake Jesus again unto them, saying, [I AM  16] The Light of the world: he that followeth Me shall not walk in darkness, but shall have the Light of Life.   John 8:12
17. [I AM  17] One that bear witness of Myself, and the Father that sent Me beareth witness of me.   John 8:18
18. I said therefore unto you, that ye shall die in your sins: for if ye believe not that [I AM  18] ~, ye shall die in your sins.   John 8:24
19. Then said Jesus unto them, When ye have lifted up The Son of man, then shall ye know that [I AM  19] ~, and that I do nothing of Myself; but as My Father hath taught Me, I speak these things.   John 8:28
20. Jesus said unto them, Amin, Amin, I say unto you, Before Abraham was, [I AM  20].   John 8:58
21. Then said Jesus unto them again, Amin, Amin, I say unto you, [I AM  21] The Door of the sheep.   John 10:7
22. [I AM  22] The Door: by Me if any man enter in, he shall be saved, and shall go in and out, and find pasture.   John 10:9
23. [I AM  23] The Good Shepherd: The Good Shepherd giveth His Life for the sheep.   John 10:11
24. [I AM  24] The Good Shepherd, and know My sheep, and am known of Mine.   John 10:14
25. Jesus said unto her, [I AM  25] The Resurrection, and The Life: he that believeth in Me, though he were dead, yet shall he live:   John 11:25
26. Now I tell you before it come, that, when it is come to pass, ye may believe that [I AM  26] ~.   John 13:19
27. Jesus saith unto Him, [I AM  27] The Way, The Truth, and The Life: no man cometh unto The Father, but by Me.   John 14:6
28. [I AM  28] The True Vine, and My Father is The Husbandman.   John 15:1
29. [I AM  29] The Vine, ye are the branches: He that abideth in Me, and I in Him, the same bringeth forth much fruit: for without Me ye can do nothing.   John 15:5
30. They answered Him, Jesus of Nazareth. Jesus saith unto them, [I AM  30] ~. And Judas also, which betrayed Him, stood with them.   John 18:5
31. As soon then as He had said unto them, [I AM  31] ~, they went backward, and fell to the ground.   John 18:6
32. Jesus answered, I have told you that [I AM  32] ~: if therefore ye seek Me, let these go their way:   John 18:8

Acts

33. And he said, Who art thou, Lord? And the Lord said, [I AM  33] Jesus whom thou persecutest: it is hard for thee to kick against the pricks.   Acts 9:5
34. For [I AM  34] with thee, and no man shall set on thee to hurt thee: for I have much people in this city.   Acts 18:10
35. And I answered, Who art thou, Lord? And he said unto me, [I AM  35] Jesus of Nazareth, whom thou persecutest.   Acts 22:8
36. And I said, Who art thou, Lord? And he said, [I AM  36] Jesus whom thou persecutest.   Acts 26:15

Apocalypse

1. [I AM  37] Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the ending, saith the Lord God, which is, and which was, and which is to come, the Almighty.   Apocalypse  1:8
2. And when I saw him, I fell at his feet as dead. And he laid his right hand upon me, saying unto me, Fear not; [I AM  38] The First and The Last:   Apocalypse  1:17
3. And I will kill her children with death; and all the churches shall know that [I AM  39] ~ which searcheth the reins and hearts: and I will give unto every one of you according to your works.   Apocalypse  2:23
4. I Jesus have sent Mine angel to testify unto you these things in The Churches. [I AM  40] The Root and The Offspring of David, and The Bright and Morning Star.   Apocalypse  22:16

source: http://www.bibleproofs.org/ia.html

Comment: Hi Silouan Mathew, welcome! What is really your question?

Comment: Matt 22:32 was a quote of God and is predicated; Matt 24:5 is also predicated; Luke 24:39 is also predicated; John 6:35, 48, 51, 8:18, 10:7, 9, 11, 14, 11:25, 14:6, 15:1, 5, Acts 9:5, 18:10, 22:8, 26:15, Rev 1:8, 17, 2:23, 22:16 are all predicated.  There are others who used predicated "I am" statements such as Gabriel, Luke 1:19, etc.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁
Thank you!

Comment: @Dottard
thank you, the angel as well as the blind man use the words 'ego eimi' (John 9:9)

the significance of the 'Ego Eimi' spoken by Christ is that when we consider the entire set of 'Ego Eimi' spoken by the Triune God, we find there are exactly 40 such instances in the whole New Testament. this forms one of the many sets of 40, 41 in the Scriptures.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁
the question, which i apologize for the lack of clarity, was more about whether the reader of the post found it compelling as an argument / proof / evidence for the Inspiration of the Holy Scriptures. this pattern occurs through out the Scriptures and i believe serves as a numerical "watermark" for the inspiration of the Scriptures.

Comment: **Voting to close as opinion-based** since it concerns a theological belief about the inspiration of the text and doesn't seek to understand a specific text, and the question "How convincing [is my argument] as proof [of a theological doctrine]?" is subjective.

Comment: the 'Ego Eimi' is understood by the Church Fathers as a reference to the Deity of Christ (as it maps to Exodus 3:14 - Revelation 1:8, and many passages in-between).

this is disputed by modern academia and non-trinitarians / muslims etc. the fact that the total number of 'EGO EIMI' spoken by the Triune God in the Greek New Testament is *exactly 40* argues against the casual dismissal of the words as insignificant.

Comment: @user48152
Christ indeed refers to the Father as God. The Father is the Source *outside of time* of the HYPOSTASIS (Person) of the Son and the Holy Spirit. 

Thus the Father BEGETS the Son (outside of time), and the Holy Spirit (eternally) PROCEEDS from the Father.

The words 'One God' is a Title for The Father, and the words 'One Lord' is a Title for The Son. Just like The Father and Holy Spirit are Lord, the Son and Holy Spirit are God. The Three Hypostases of The Holy Trinity are ONE in Essence (OUSIA). The Son is ONE with the Father - that is He is One with the One God.

Comment: ty - much of which have zero biblical substantiation. Make of that what you may. Do we trust God's revelation through the bible or men's fanciful ideas that contradict the bible? Take 'Jesus and the Father are equal' and find any verse to support that idea.

Comment: @user48152
The 'Name' (ONOMA) of God | {Matthew, Mark, Luke} | 40 instances.

References to the word NAME in the context of the "Name" of God

http://www.bibleproofs.org/nm.a.html

Comment: @user48152

The 'Name' (ONOMA) of God | Corpus of John | 40 instances. 
http://www.bibleproofs.org/nm.b.html

Answer (score 2):

“I am” in the Greek (NT) is, “ego eimi”.  The verb, “eimi” occurs 2462 times in the New Testament in various forms, but in only about 67 of these cases is the first person nominative pronoun, “ego” used with it.  Generally, the complete form, “ego eimi” only occurs when some emphasis is required.

This present continuous verb, “to be”, is the most common in almost all languages and has several syntactical functions in Greek (eg, see John 1:1 ):

- Existence, “I am.”, ie, unpredicated (see below).
- Identification, eg, Luke 1:19, “I am Gabriel”; John 9:9, “I am [that one]”; John 10:11, “I am the good shepherd”.
- Relationship, eg, Acts 18:10, “I am with you”.
- Predication, eg, Acts 22:3, “I am Jewish”.

The New Testament shows an interesting and (somewhat) unexpected pattern in the use of the Greek phrase, “ego eimi”, “I am”.

The exact phrase “ego eimi” occurs 48 times in the New Testament.  It also occurs 11 times as “eimi ego” which has a very similar but still different construction and all are relational or predicative.  It occurs in a few other forms such as “ego gar eimi”, “ego men eimi”, “ego ouk eimi” (I am not), etc, a total of 67 times (one or two are disputed).  Of the 48 cases of the exact phrase “ego eimi”, “I am”, just 15 are unpredicated and have (with one exception) the syntactical form existence as opposed to identification, relationship or predication.  All are listed below (my translation) unless preceded by “not”, eg, Matt 26:22, 25, plus one exception to be noted.

- Matt 14:27, Mark 6:50 – “Be encouraged.  I am.”  [To the frightened disciples in the boat.]
- Mark 13:6, Luke 21:8 – “Many will come in my name saying, ‘I am’”.
- Mark 14:62, Luke 22:70 – “Jesus replied, ‘I am’”.  [He was then accused of blasphemy by the Jews and condemned.]
- John 4:26 – “Then Jesus said, ‘I am.’”  [To the Samaritan woman at the well.  There is a reasonable case for this being identification, but that is a matter of taste.]
- John 6:20 – “But then [Jesus] said to them, ‘I am.  Fear not.’”  [To the frightened disciples in the boat.]
- John 8:24 – “If you do not trust/believe that I am, you will die in your sins.”
- John 8:28 – “When you will lift up the Son of Man, then you will trust/know that I am.”
- John 8:58 – “Truly, truly, I say to you; before Abraham existed, I am.”  [The Jews then tried to stone Him for blasphemy.]  Note that this and the previous two mean that Jesus, in the space of this chapter of John 8 uses the unpredicated “I am” idea in the present (v24), future (v28) and past sense (v58).  V24 & 28 appears to be tied to believers’ salvation as well.
- John 9:9 – “Some were saying that, ‘this is [that one]’, and others were saying ‘no, it is like him.’  But he was saying, ‘I am [that one].’” (This instance is clearly identification rather than existence, as there is an implied, "that man" after the "I am".)
- John 13:19 – “From now [on] I tell you before the occurrence, that you may believe when it occurs that, I am.”
- John 18: 5, 6, 8 – “He said to them, ‘I am.’ …Therefore, when He told them, ‘I am’, they fell backward to the ground.”  [This occurred when the Jews tried to arrest Jesus in the garden.  It could be reasonably argued that this is a case of identification.  However, the fact that the arresting mob fell backward suggests that much more is intended here.]

It is interesting that, according to Mark 13:6 and Luke 21:8, one of the distinguishing characteristics of false christs is their claim to be “I AM”.  Unfortunately, there has been a historical parade of charlatans making such false claims.

Thus, with the obvious and rather trivial exception of John 9:9 (and self-exclusory Mark 13:6 and Luke 21:8), all of the “I am” existence statements in the New Testament, including the 7 in John, were spoken exclusively by Jesus, and all were either the basis for absolute trust/belief and reassurance in Jesus, or were a clear declaration of His claim to be the “I AM.”

Comment: thank you, apparently, the number of instances this is spoken by God in the New Testament is **exactly 40** times (which was the reason for the post)

this is one of many instances of this pattern of 40 and 41 in the Scriptures.

the Greek word 'proskuneo' (WORSHIP) forms another set:
http://www.bibleproofs.org/wr.html

Comment: may i ask why you mention the number 14? is it because of it being mentioned 3 times in Matthew's Genealogy of Christ? (Matthew Chapter 1)

Comment: so you are aware then of the 3 sets of 14 mentioned in Matthew?

Comment: This is not kabbalistic in the least.

Comment: The reason I asked you about the three sets of 14 is this. Do you know how many male ancestors of Christ are listed in Matthew's 3 sets of 14?

Comment: Can you agree (from the Holy Scriptures) that the number 40 is mentioned a great many times in the context of time (40 days and 40 years)?

Comment: In between the two durations of time {40 days} and {40 years} is 40 weeks. Do you know what the 40 weeks is referring to?

Comment: yes, specifically The Incarnation of The Lord which contains within it the Mystery of the Cosmos and Time